# found staticlib `std` instead of rlib or dylib

Tags: substrate, polkadot, rust-crates

found staticlib `std` instead of rlib or dylib

help: please recompile that crate using --crate-type lib
note: the following crate versions were found:
crate `std`: C:\Users.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\std-77c29e3b2a96c9a6.dll.librustc(E0462)
found staticlib `std` instead of rlib or dylib

help: please recompile that crate using --crate-type lib
note: the following crate versions were found:
crate `std`: C:\Users.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\std-77c29e3b2a96c9a6.dll.librustc(E0462)

How to recompile that crate using --crate-type lip ?
I am doing https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To add to the above comment, would you be so kind as to repost this (edited) great question on https://substrate.stackexchange.com/ -- and @NukeManDan over there?
Very happy to assist on our shiny new Substrate (and friends) home for your questions!